# How to change the Android AlertDialog selection background color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

[image]

I'm using Alert Dialog in android , I need to change the background Color while selecting how can i do it ?

if you check the image second line "Right" is selected but not visible properly so i want to change it to darker color.

```
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ModeActivity.this);
    builderSingle.setTitle("Select Part");

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            ABIModeActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    arrayAdapter.add("1");
    arrayAdapter.add("2");
    arrayAdapter.add("3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below code for style:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/myColor</item>
</style>
```

Now this style apply on dialog:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.MyDialogTheme)
```

Comment: I'm Not using in Fragment

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(BIModeActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog);

Comment: i want to change the background selection , i have added an image in my question can you check it .

Comment: See my final answer if this is useful then pin me if not then also pin me @RagulRg

Comment: finally it worked with some more modifications. Thank you

Comment: welcome :) i also say hasss it's work now :) :) @RagulRg

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the `background` color try :

```
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

 dialog.show();

 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(ModeActivity.this, R.style.Your_App_theme);`

and Add theme in style.xml:

```
<style name="Your_App_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```